# Lambdas are restricted to a single expression! Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

From a tutorial:

> With the *lambda* keyword, small anonymous functions can be created. ...
>   They are syntactically restricted to a single expression.

Why on Earth does this limitation exist?

Comment: Why don't we just use `lambda` in place of regular functions for everything then so we don't have to type a `return`? That's starting to sound like perl to me. (Keep in mind Guido hates `lambda`s and almost had them removed)